# automake - how to change permissions to an installed binary

Tags: autotools, automake

I have this Makefile.am:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects
sbin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = foo.c

install-exec-hook:
    chmod +s $(sbindir)/foo
```

everything works well except for the target *distcheck* which gives this error:

```
> make distcheck
...
...
...
Making install in sub-module
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/users/a/myproj/_build/sub-module'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/users/a/myproj/_build/sub-module'
 ../../install-sh -c -d '/var/folders/pp/jbr_vq091s7gd8x9scrc7drw0000gn/T//am-dc-71151//home/users/a/myproj/_inst/sbin'
    /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c foo '/var/folders/pp/jbr_vq091s7gd8x9scrc7drw0000gn/T//am-dc-71151//home/users/a/myproj/_inst/sbin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c foo /var/folders/pp/jbr_vq091s7gd8x9scrc7drw0000gn/T//am-dc-71151//home/users/a/myproj/_inst/sbin/foo
make  install-exec-hook
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/users/a/myproj/_build/sub-module'
chmod +s /home/users/a/myproj/_inst/sbin/foo
chmod: /home/users/a/myproj/_inst/sbin/foo: No such file or directory
Makefile:645: recipe for target 'install-exec-hook' failed
make[4]: *** [install-exec-hook] Error 1
```

it looks like the *foo* binary is copied to some temp directory (/var/folders/pp/jbr_vq091s7gd8x9scrc7drw0000gn/T//am-dc-71151//home/users/a/myproj/_inst/sbin) and not to where it is looked at in the install-exec-hook target (/home/users/a/myproj/_inst/sbin)

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say how you configured or the exact command you used for `make install`.  This matters for two reasons:

1. Automake supports renaming files at install time via configure's `--program-prefix` and related options;
2. Automake supports setting `DESTDIR` at installation-time.

So maybe one of these is having an effect.

Fixing the renaming issue is a bit involved -- see the Autoconf documentation -- but dealing with `DESTDIR` at least is simple:

```
install-exec-hook:
       chmod +s $(DESTDIR)$(sbindir)/foo
```

Note the lack of a directory separator between the two variables.  That is intentional.

If this doesn't help then you need to investigate earlier to find where that strange prefix is coming from.  I don't believe there is anything in Automake that would add it.

Comment: actually my flow is very straight forward:
> env LIBTOOLIZE=glibtoolize autoreconf --install|
> ./configure
> make
> make distcheck

so, I really don't know where that destination dir came from. 
Anyway, your solution did help. Adding $(DESTDIR) solved it.